# Trying to show that $a^2\neq b^2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am working in a group $G=\{1,a,b,b^2,ab,ba\}$, where $a,b$ are unique. There is no mention of abelian-ness but I know $|G|=6$, i.e. $ab$ and $ba$ are unique elements (I suppose this takes away the possibility that $G$ is abelian). I have to find the order of elements in the group. Clearly $|x|=1,2,3,6$ by Lagrange. Since $a,b$ are unique, it must be that $|a|=2$ or $3$. I am trying to argue $|a|=2$, such that $a^2=e$. To do this, it suffices to show that $a^2$ is no other group element. Note that in what follows, I use $\perp$ to denote a contradiction.

1. $a^2\neq a$ since otherwise $a=e$.
2. $a^2\neq b\implies ba^{-1}=a^{-1}b\implies ba=ab \perp$.
3. $a^2=ab\implies a=b\perp$.
4. $a^2=ba\implies a=b\perp$.

I am struggling with the final case, $a^2=b^2$. Here is my attempt:

> Suppose $a^2=b^2$. Then $abba=baab$. I suspect there is some clever way of arriving at a contradiction from this point, but I am confused about how to do so. I have tried using inverse arguments, but I can't seem to get a contradictory form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is only one non-abelian group of order $6$, $S_3$.

Comment: I do not understand $2.$. If we assume $a^2=b$, how do you conclude $ba^{-1}=a^{-1}b$ ? Moreover how do you conclude from this $ba=ab$ ?

Comment: @Peter If $a^2=b$, then $a=a^{-1}b$, but also using the right-inverse, $a=ba^{-1}$, so $a^{-1}b=ba^{-1}$. Now, act on the RHS and LHS of both sides with $a$. This gives $aa^{-1}ba=aba^{-1}a\implies ab=ba$.

Comment: @W.Ryan Now it became clear.

Answer (score 3):

For a purely group theoretic method, note the following facts follow from $a^2=b^2$:

1. $a^2=b^2\implies aabb=bbaa=baab=abba$.
2. $a^2=b^2\implies a=a^{-1}b^2=b^2a^{-1}$.

Start with $abba=baab$, and rewrite the RHS using $a=b^2a^{-1}$ to obtain $abba=bb^2a^{-1}aab=b^3ab$. Now use the fact that $abba=bbaa$ to rewrite this as $bbaa=b^3ab$ so $a^2=bab$. But $a^2=b^2$ so $b^2=bab\implies a=e$, which is a clear contradiction.